# Replace a word on lines matching two conditions

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to replace `defaults` with `defaults,nodev` for `/`, `/home`, `/opt`, `/tmp`, `/var`.

However `defaults` setting should not be changed for `swap` and `proc`.

This is the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/dev/rootvg/swap     swap                swap       defaults              0 0
/dev/rootvg/sysroot  /                   ext3       defaults              1 1
/dev/sda1            /boot               ext3       acl,user_xattr        1 2
/dev/rootvg/home     /home               ext3       defaults              1 2
/dev/rootvg/opt      /opt                ext3       defaults              1 2
/dev/rootvg/tmp      /tmp                ext3       defaults              1 2
/dev/rootvg/var      /var                ext3       defaults              1 2
proc                 /proc               proc       defaults              0 0
sysfs                /sys                sysfs      noauto                0 0
debugfs              /sys/kernel/debug   debugfs    noauto                0 0
devpts               /dev/pts            devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this `sed` command will help to you

```
sed '/proc\|swap/!s/defaults/&,nodev/' /etc/fstab
```

**Output:**

```
/dev/rootvg/swap     swap                swap       defaults              0 0
/dev/rootvg/sysroot  /                   ext3       defaults,nodev              1 1
/dev/sda1            /boot               ext3       acl,user_xattr        1 2
/dev/rootvg/home     /home               ext3       defaults,nodev              1 2
/dev/rootvg/opt      /opt                ext3       defaults,nodev              1 2
/dev/rootvg/tmp      /tmp                ext3       defaults,nodev              1 2
/dev/rootvg/var      /var                ext3       defaults,nodev              1 2
proc                 /proc               proc       defaults              0 0
sysfs                /sys                sysfs      noauto                0 0
debugfs              /sys/kernel/debug   debugfs    noauto                0 0
devpts               /dev/pts            devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0 0
```

**Note:**
If you want changes in file use `-i` option

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{` to combine two regex adresses:

```
/^\//{/swap/!s/defaults/defaults,nodev/}
```

More verbosely:

```
#!/bin/sed
/^\//{
/swap/!s/defaults/defaults,nodev/
}
```

So on lines that begin with `/`, then if that line doesn't contain `swap`, then do the substitution.

In fact, for that particular file, all the disk filesystems are `ext3`, so you could simplify to just

```
/ext3/s/defaults/defaults,nodev/
```

Comment: `/var` is changed too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to change the option for all `ext3` file systems. then you can:

```
sed '/ext[2-4]/s/defaults/&,nodev/' file
```

with this line, it will apply the substitution on `ext2, 3, 4` FS. You can adjust it if you want , e.g. `ext3` for ext3 only. But this may not always give you correct result, since regex was used.

If you have to do the substitution for certain mount point, I would use awk check the column and I won't use regex either.